# $R[x]/(f)$ is free over $R$ implies that $R[x]/(f) \to Q \otimes R[x]/(f)$ is a monomorphism

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, free-modules

I have a question about the proof of corollary 4.12. in Eisenbuds "Commutative Algebra with a view towards Algebraic Geometry":

> If $R$ is a normal domain, then any monic irreducible polynomial in $R[x]$ is prime.

I understand the argument in the proof except one detail: naturally $R[x]/(f)$ is a free $R$-module, and letting $Q$ be the field of fractions of $R$, it's claimed that the injection $R[x]/(f) \to Q \otimes R[x]/(f)$ a monomorphism. Why is it necessarily a monomorphism? Maybe the reason I'm confused is because I'm not sure how an element of $R[x]/(f)$ is mapped to $Q \otimes R[x]/(f)$.

Comment: $R \to Q\otimes_R R=Q$ is injective and similarly $R^n \to Q \otimes_R R^n=Q^n$ is injective. The map $R[x]/(f) \to Q\otimes R[x]/(f)$ is defined via $r \mapsto 1\otimes r$, but this can be identified (on the level of $R$-modules) with the inclusion $R^n \hookrightarrow Q^n$

Comment: @LukasHeger Of course, I knew it had to be something easy... Thank you!